# How does BlueJeans estimate the number of meeting participants?

Tags: bluejeans

When I go to a BlueJeans video recording, I see the number of meeting participants:

[image]

How does BlueJeans estimate the number of meeting participants?

It doesn't correspond to the number of connections to the corresponding BlueJeans meeting ID. In the example from the screenshot, the number of connections to the corresponding BlueJeans meeting ID was below 10, whereas BlueJeans estimate of the number of meeting participants was 17. Clicking on "17 participants" show less than 10 people.

Comment: How many participants did you send the invite to?  Were the same 10 participants always connected, and perhaps, it was 17 different participants?  Edit your question to include this vital information.

Comment: @Ramhound no idea, I didn't record/attend the meeting.

Comment: You have absolutely no idea how many people you sent the invite to?  This is required information to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound this wasn't meeting organized by me. I wasn't invited. I only have a link to the recording.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without that information.  From what I can tell, the number isn’t an estimation though, and is an accurate representation of the number of participants that attended the meeting

Comment: @Ramhound yes it can.

Comment: @fixer1234 "this might be the kind of question to ask the developers or sales people," -> isn't that true for most questions on a program?

Comment: @fixer1234  "the algorithm is the kind of information likely to be proprietary, so there is no way to independently validate any answer. " -> the information could be publicly available. Proprietary doesn't mean private. Patents aren't private.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Nope; I can answer almost any questions about Windows, and I do not work at Microsoft, same applies to most Windows software honestly.

Comment: @Ramhound Users with experience with BlueJeans may know the answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes they could know it only if it's documented somewhere (or if the technical support is okay to share the information). This is true for most questions on  programs. Regarding  your link to meta, my question falls under "Questions about observable behavior of running software".

Comment: OK, based on your answer, I'd say this is publicly available information, so I'll retract the close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the BlueJeans technical support:

> The platform summarizes the participant count over the entire call but those participants aren’t necessarily unique. If you and I were having a meeting and you dropped and rejoined the total participant count would be three.
>
> The meeting shows multiple people connecting multiple times making a total of 17 but concurrent is 9. If you click on the blue text it will open a list and show you the breakdown.
>
> Lastly, the recording connection may count as one, when you click record a recording platform joins the meeting as a video/audio connection so if the number is off by one that is why.

Comment: +1 for the research effort, perseverance, and finally putting this sucker to bed.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 yep mystery solved!